# Select records from MYSQL database grouped by day

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, timestamp

I have a database of records that have a timestamp asscoiated with them. I would like to pull records from the database grouped by day, so if there are other records with the same date (24 hour span) I would like them to be grouped together. Can this be done with MYSQL or will I have to pull the records and organise them into arrays using PHP?

Here is a screenshot of my table:

[image]

Here is my model function so far:

```
public function getUsersMoves($options) {   
        $query = "SELECT * FROM myzone_user_hr_records";
        if(isset($options['GUID'])) {
            $query .= " WHERE GUID = '" . $options['GUID'] . "'";
        }
        if((isset($options['minHR'])) &&  isset($options['maxHR'])) {
            $query .= " AND (hr BETWEEN '" . (int)$options['minHR'] . "' AND '" . (int)$options['maxHR'] . "')";
        } else if (isset($options['zone'])) {
            $query .= " AND zone = '" . (int)$options['zone'] . "'";
        }
        if(isset($options['activity'])) {
            $query .= " AND title = '" . $options['activity'] . "'";
        }

        $query .= " ORDER BY time DESC";

        $query = $this->db->query($query);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

And my controller code:

```
$moves = $this->myzone_model->getUsersMoves($options);
```

I want the data sorted so that these records are grouped together if they have the same date in the timestamp, for example (2012-11-20).

Thanks

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: You can use group by when you used some aggregate function only in the select statement......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this :

```
SELECT *, DATE(time) AS date FROM [whatever you want] GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from TABLE where `time` like '2012-11-20%'
```

The option I have suggested works because the LIKE condition in the WHERE selects all dates from the time field that start with `2012-11-20`.  That means that it doesn't matter what time it is during the day, it will return all results for that day.

To make this work, you must remember to use LIKE and then add the wildcard at the end - `%`.  You can also add the wildcard at the beginning if you wanted.  An example to return all days (11th December) for multiple years would be:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE `time` like '%-12-11%'
```

Comment: It would be great if you explained it.

Comment: @wtsang02 There isn't really anything to explain here.  You simply query the table and there is a WHERE condition on the field TIME using a wildcard.  The LIKE part means that it doesn't literally compare, it only compares the first part (the day / month / year combo) and the rest can be anything (because of the wildcard).  So any different times (within the same day) still get returned.

If you wish to read more, check out:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html

Comment: The system will automatically flag as low quality if you type too little as the answer. It always better to add some explaination to code.

Comment: @wtsang02 oh ok, I wasn't aware that the system did that.  I always wondered why people seemed to write 10,000 words when it could be explained just as easily in 100 :) I will update the answer to make it clearer.